# How to uninstall apache2 on macOS Sierra 10.13.1

Tags: macos, sh

I am using Sierra 10.13.1
I have ran 'sudo apachectl stop' but still work 'localhost'. I have checked 'sudo lsof -I TCP:80'

> httpd        74     root    4u  IPv6 0x7f0262e9f581b6f5      0t0  TCP
>   *:http (LISTEN)
>
> httpd       254     _www    4u  IPv6 0x7f0262e9f581b6f5      0t0  TCP
>   *:http (LISTEN)

Im not sure what is service 
how to fix this issue
Thanks for your advance.

Comment: which `apachectl` are you using?  One that comes with macOS or one that you installed via brew?  What happens when you type in `type apachectl`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and probably belongs on **Ask Different**.

Comment: I am using apache from macOS sierra 10.13